# como criar um .bat que crie outro .bat com mais de um comando?

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

eu quero criar um arquivo .bat que crie outro arquivo .bat, mas quando eu tento criar eu nao consigo botar mais de um comando.

exemplo: eu tenho o meu arquivo teste.bat que vai criar outro arquivo chamado teste2.bat entao eu usei esse codigo:

```
echo msg * ola > teste2.bat
```

mas se eu for usar ele para dois comandos como:

```
echo msg * ola start chrome > teste2.bat
```

ele acaba dando erro, tem alguma forma de fazer este arquivo executar mais de um comando?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta usar sinal de mais ">>" duplos para que você adicione os novos comandos ao final do arquivo ao invêz sobreescrever os comandos que já existem no novo bat...

```
echo msg * ola >> teste2.bat
echo start chrome >> teste2.bat
```